# Cognos SDK documentation / tutorial or something like that

Tags: sdk, cognos, cognos-bi

I need to embed cognos analytics reports in my web application with a high degree of integration such as custom UI of reports list, custom UI of report controls and so one. As far as I understand sdk is intended for this purpose, but i cant find any normal guide / tutorial, even hello world example of SDK usage. Please, tell me where it can be found?

Comment: I think IBM and SAP are competing for who can produce the most complicated product w/ the worst documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Software Development Kit Developer Guide is available online : 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_10.2.2/kc_gen/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.cbi.doc_dev_toc-gen8.html

You can find a pdf version of this documentation after the installation of the SDK component of Cognos 10.x (can't find a pdf version for cognos 11.x but it's probably the same guide)...

Default path : `C:\Program Files\ibm\cognos\c10_64\webcontent\documentation\en\dg_sdk.pdf`

And finaly you can find a lot of SDK samples in this place : 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/search.wss?q=SDK%20Sample